# Emacs, switching to another frame (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, emacs

I can switch between windows with "C-x o", but if I have opened multiple frames, can I move between them without the mouse as well?

I just realized that the question probably sounds braindead without this detail: I'm on Mac OS X (Finnish keyboard) and switching between windows of the same application is difficult.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want an Emacs-centric method, try C-x 5 o.

Answer (score 26):

Put this in your .emacs

(global-set-key "\M-`" 'other-frame)

Then you can do Command-` to switch between emacs frames.

Comment: because M+` is more Mac native, and less key pressed, so I prefer this than C-x 5 o way...

Comment: I have osx-key-mode enabled by default, it does the same biding.

Answer (score 10):

I use M-x next-multiframe-window (bound to a key of course). Better IMHO than M-x other-frame (C-x 5 o).

next-multiframe-window steps thorough the windows of each frame. other-frame toggles just steps through the frames (like ALT-TAB)

Answer (score 9):

I recently [answered a similar question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/104456/quickly-navigating-emacs-buffers-on-a-dual-display-setup/111169#111169).  There's a new package called [`framemove.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/framemove.el), which lets you easily switch frames using the arrow keys (with a prefix key like <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>meta</kbd>).

To install:

```
(require 'framemove)
(framemove-default-keybindings) ;; default prefix is Meta
```

Answer (score 4):

From [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frame-Commands.html) the answer is "C-x 5 o" (but read the fine print at the and - about variable *focus-follows-mouse*)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can switch between frames the same way you switch between applications.

On Windows I use Alt-TAB, on Unix I have my machine setup to use Ctrl-Alt-TAB

Comment: Yes, I'm on OS X and there switching between windows of the same app is a  PITA.

Comment: On OS X you can also use Command-` / Command-~ to cycle windows of the same app (it may be different on non-US keyboard layouts if you can't type that key easily, try holding down Command and pressing the key above tab.)  I actually use that more commonly than C-x 5 o with Emacs.

Comment: The comment from @NicholasRiley just above (M-` / Command-` ) once worked but is broken/triggers something else in recent versions of emacs, where it triggers a keyboard-driven menu.  One can use that menu, or rebind things.  (Command-` still works in most Mac apps).  John Newlin's solution works to rebind things so it works again. :-). Haven't tried schatten's suggestion, but seems like a great one.  I find C-x 5 o doesn't work with ediff.